# Search and Replace in all files in VSCode behaves different compared to search and replace inside a file

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have several functions across different files, and they usually are like this:
`"prefix":"functionName (...)"`, like `pub:isInt`. And I wanted to put the first letter of the function as capital, so I did this regex to change to `pub:IsInt` (this also rejects other non-intented matches, that is why it is like this):

MATCH: `([a-z]+):([a-z])([a-z \t_:]*)?(?=\()`

REPLACE: `$1:\U$2$3`

---

This works fine for one function, the problem is when I have several functions in the same line, like:

```
pv:collect(table | pv:hasElement(table) AND pv:element(table))
```

Search and Replace in multiple files does this:

```
pv:Collect(table | pv:Collect(table) AND pv:Collect(table))
```

which is wrong because `$1`, `$2` and `$3` match only the first for the whole line.

Search and Replace in one file does the correct:

```
pv:Collect(table | pv:HasElement(table) AND pv:Element(table))
```

---

**I think the problem is on the lookahead's (`(?=\()`) parsing problem**. Because if I do the same, but removing the lookahead and doing a greedy match `*?`, it works both in for all files and inside a file.
`([a-z]+):([a-z])([\w \t_:]*?\()`

Comment: I have edited the question to improve its formatting. Please check that my changes correctly interpret the question and, if not correct, then [edit] it as needed. (I do not have an answer to the question.)

Comment: I have VSCode 1.83.1 and can confirm this behavior. This is maybe a case for the [VSCode issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) and if you cannot find that problem there post a new issue.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an actual bug in VSCode

I've created an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196592

[image]

---

Try using regex without lookahead:

```
([a-z]+):([a-z])([a-z \t_:]*)?\(
$1:\U$2$3(
```

Comment: @lmmr  try not using lookahead (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will match more than you think, see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VNF9NR/1).

VS Code will produce 2 matches as well **IF** you enable the `MatchCase` option - otherwise it'll treat your `[a-z]` as `[a-zA-Z]`.

Perhaps you can use `^` at the beginning of the regex like:

```
^([a-z]+):([a-z])([a-zA-Z \t_:]*)?(?=\()    // need for the MatchCase option
```

You see I added `A-Z` so you don't need the `MatchCase` option.

I think what you really want is

```
([a-z]+):([a-z])([\w \t_:|()]*)(?=\()
```

I added `|()` to your character class.  And I used `\w` so it handles both lower and upper characters.  See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/rxdeR7/1) and tested in vscode.

Comment: No, the latest regex seem to not be working. I don't want to match the '()' because then I will end match the last function in the line only.